# A function is given by a formula. Determine whether it is one-to-one. $g(x) = \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus

Why is $g(x) = \cos(x)$ not a one to one function? Is it because the unit circle repeats itself for different values? How can I understand this distinction when it comes to recognizing a one to one function?

Comment: Because on a wide interval or the whole $\mathbb R$ it is 1) not injective, and 2) not onto.

Comment: One-to-one from which set to which set? It is for sure a one-to-one function from $\{0\}$ to $\{1\}$.

Comment: Use the "horizontal line test".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply to ease your understanding, One-One means that for each(one) element of x there should exist only one unique value of g(x). But for cos(x) function, for x=0, 2π, 4π,....(2nπ) we get same value of g(x) that is 1. So there is more than one relation from x to g(x), so we say g(x) is not one-one.

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your are right if your considering an interval of all real numbers. A function is 1-1 if and only if:

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$

Means:

$$x_1=x_2$$

But for $cosx$:

$$cos(x+2\pi)=cos(x)$$

And:

$$x+2\pi \neq x$$

This is a result of cosines period. Any function that is periodic is not 1-1 because $f(x)=c$ will happen at more than one value for $x$.

If you only consider $x: [0,\pi]$ than $cosx$ is 1-1 as no values of $y=f(x)$ will be repeated. This is because once $cos(x)$ reaches a min of $-1$ at $x=\pi$ it will need to go back up again and thus values after $x=\pi$ will be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\cos(x)=\cos(x+2\pi k)$$
for all $k\in\mathbb Z$. That's why cosine can't be one to one.

But if you restrict the cosine function to a small interval it is one to on. For example $\cos:[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ is one to one.